# COBOL if else-if statements, proper way to use them

Tags: if-statement, cobol

I'm new to COBOL and want to write a nested if statement. I'm getting errors on the ELSE-IF and ELSE.  I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
reading-procedure.
       display "Enter Type of Pet: " with no advancing.
       accept pet.
       display "Enter Appointment Fee: " with no advancing.
       accept fee.
       IF pet = 'dog' 
       add fee total giving dogTotal.
       add 1 to dogCount.
       ELSE-IF pet = 'cat' 
       add fee total giving catTotal.
       add 1 to catCount.
       ELSE
       add fee total giving otherTotal.
       add 1 to otherCount.
       END-IF
```

Comment: Did you find an answer that "works for you"? If yes please accept (it currently is "open"),  otherwise I suggest to comment on the answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is no (standard) `else-if` statement in COBOL.
In most cases where you have multiple branches `EVALUATE TRUE` with `WHEN condition-1  <statements>  WHEN condition-2  <statements> [...] END-EVALUATE` is what you want to use - and in cases like your sample you can do `EVALUATE pet WHEN 'dog' ... WHEN 'cat' ... END-EVALUATE`.

The reason why you are getting syntax errors for `ELSE` is simple: you end them with your periods - get rid of them (the only part where you need them within `PROCEDURE DIVISION` is before and after a paragraph/section/entry definition.